# Logon screen - changing automatically

Tags: windows, windows-7, wallpaper

I've change logon screen based on this "tutorial":
http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-windows-7-logon-screen-easily-without-using-hacks-tools/

So I've created a folder/key in register and if I'll lock the computer it works as it should.

Unfortunately after few minutes picture which was set by me in the windows folder is overwritten by some "Company Crap Wallpaper".

`Does anyone know how to switch-off automatic updates of logon screen ?`

Comment: It's strange that your logon wallpaper was changed by some third-parties.
Do you have computer from some big brand, say like Toshiba, Sony, etc.? Because there must be some process running in background, looking for changes in your registry key.


Also, what do you mean, by 
>> overwritten by some "Company Crap Wallpaper".<<


Can you give us some details? I would look for "company crap (wallpaper) process in your computer.

Comment: yes it looks like some process is doing that however I cannot thing of a method how to find it ... 
It's HP.

Answer (score 0):

- Download [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/) and use Process Monitor to find out which process is overwriting your wallpaper in

  ```
   %windir%\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds
  ```

  Then you can kill/block/delete this process.
- Use third-party [logon wallpaper changer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=logon%20wallpaper%20changer), although i wouldn't install that closed-source programs on my system.